# How to return concatenated attribute values of certain elements on a page as a string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to collect the source urls of certain images on a page to return them as a string. Now I found out how to do this with the use of jquery (see below); however, from where the code is executed, jquery is not available. How does the example below translate to pure Javascript?

```
var x = $('div.class > img').map(function(){
return "\"www.website.com" + $(this).attr('src') + "\"";
}).get().join(',');
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('div.class > img')` can be written as `[...document.querySelectorAll('div.class > img')]`

`$(this).attr('src')` is equivellent to `elem.getAttribute('src')` (where `elem` is passed through the function)

This will give you the following output:

```js
var x = [...document.querySelectorAll('div.class > img')].map(function(elem) {
  return "\"www.website.com" + elem.getAttribute('src') + "\"";
}).join(',');

console.log(x);
```

```html
<div class="class">
  <img src="img1.png" alt="img1" />
  <img src="img1.png" alt="img2" />
  <img src="img1.png" alt="img3" />
</div>
```

Comment: @blindfury no worries!

Answer (score 0):

Like this,

```
var x = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.class > img')).map(function(node){
    return "\"www.website.com" + node.getAttribute("src") + "\""
}).join(',');
```